# Yii2 : how to use deleteAll with two conditions = and NOT IN

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I am trying to delete data from `RestoFoods` model like that:

```
RestoFoods::deleteAll(["restaurant_id"=>$postData['resto_id'], 'food_id NOT IN'=> [1,2] ]);
```

I want this sql:

```
DELETE FROM `resto_foods` WHERE `restaurant_id`=1 AND (`food_id` NOT IN (1, 2));
```

Comment: Make examples more readable

Answer (score 9):

You can try this way

```
RestoFoods::deleteAll(['AND', 'restaurant_id = :restaurant_id', ['NOT IN', 'food_id', [1,2]]], [':restaurant_id' => $postData['resto_id']]);
```

Output for this will be you want:

```
DELETE FROM `resto_foods` WHERE (restaurant_id = 1) AND (`food_id` NOT IN (1, 2));
```